# Trigger hover with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

How do I achive this

```
$("#a").parent().trigger('hover')
```

with jQuery? The code is not working for me.

Comment: You will need to tell us what it is you want to do. That code is vliad jQuery and is indeed doing exactly what it is supposed to do, but that is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: the code is valid, but its not working for me. Is there any other way to achive this..?

Comment: Again: We can not read your mind. *Achive what?*

Comment: trying to trigger a hover event on anchor previous element                                    <span id='text'>Text</span>                                                                          <a href="#" id="a"></a>                                                                                     i.e. on span element

Comment: Please add any extra information to the original question by editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by TJ Crowder and Endel, this can not be done directly. However, you can achieve the effect of the `span` having the hover style applied to it by adding a class.

First, change your CSS so it looks like this:

```
#text:hover, #text.hovered
{
    /* Your styles. */
}
```

That means that the same styles will be applied to `text` when it is hovered and when it has the class hovered. Then just add the class whenever you want to have the hover affect:

```
$("#a").parent().addClass('hovered');
```

And remove it when you no longer want it:

```
$("#a").parent().removeClass('hovered');
```

Comment: so i think this is not possible $('#a').parent().trigger(), trigger after parent

Answer (score 3):

Two different answers depending on what you're really asking:

#### If you've hooked up a handler using `hover` and are trying to trigger it.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

So if you want to trigger the handler for `mouseenter`, trigger `mouseenter`. If you want to trigger the handler for `mouseleave`, trigger `mouseleave`.

Note, though, that generally it's better just to call your function directly than to call it indirectly by triggering the event.

#### If you're trying to trigger the CSS for an element being "hovered"

...you can't. Instead, define a class that does the same thing, and add that class to the element.

Comment: What i trying to do is to trigger hover on anchor previous element, so that on hover anchor previous element css automatically applies, which is written in css for hover event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force a fake "hover" event in the DOM.

If you just want to change the appearance of the button, add a class to it instead.